# How to display long item name from database into pdf table properly

Tags: php, html, pdf

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item_tb WHERE warranty_id = $war_id;";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$count = 1;

while ($row_it = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $pdf->Cell(14, 10, $count, 1, 0);

    $pdf->Cell(58, 10, $row_it['item_name'], 1, 0);

    $pdf->Cell(58, 10, $row_it['serial_number'], 1, 0);

    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, $row_it['warranty_duration'] . ' bulan', 1, 0, 'C');

    $pdf->Cell(35, 10, date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row_it['expired_warranty'])), 1, 1, 'C');

    $count++;
}
```

This is my current code for output it work well if the item name short but if the item name is long, some part of the name will go into serial column.

Comment: Which library do you use to create the PDF document?

Comment: The libary i use is FPDF.

Comment: Have a look at `MultiCell()` in the manual. It can print multiple cells, one below the other, using automatic line breaks or `\n`. Note that automatic breaks are done on spaces, so if your item name is one long string it won't work. You have to insert `\n` yourself in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap the text so that it may increase the height automatically.

You need `MultiCell` here

```
$pdf->MultiCell( 200, 40, $row_it['item_name'], 1);
```

Here is the [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm)

> MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align
>   [, boolean fill]]])

Answer (score 0):

$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],58, 10, $row_it['item_name'], 1, 0);
try this if you want to increase width you can increase the width number.

Comment: Yes, but if possible i would like it to be on next line which is mostly i must use the multicell.